# Android bundles passing Pointer or copies of objects

Tags: android

If I attach an object to a bundle and store the bundle in an intent and start another activity, does that activity work on a copy of the original object or does it use the same object but just passes along a pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java there is no such thing as pointers. You can either pass and object by value or by reference.

CommonsWare [listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470520/passing-class-instances-between-applications-in-android) the possibilities the following way:

> 1. Use remote services and AIDL to implement a remote procedure call,
>      effectively giving you "pass by
>      reference" between apps
> 2. Use Parceable and Intent extras, effectively giving you "pass by value"
>      between apps

So you pass your objects by value.